# A generic entity comparison expression builder

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

As stated [here](http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2008/02/26/entity-framework-comparison-frustration-explained.aspx) EntityFramework (at least in version 6) does not support user types comparison (and thus, entities comparison) which is not practical for an ORM.

I have a scenario where I have a lot of code that does entities comparison that should be translated to SQL.
All my entities have an Id field of type int.

```
class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

For queries where I want to compare entities in a Where clause, I would like to be able the compiler to detect if trying to perform an invalid comparison.

Considere the following classes :

```
class SomeEntity : Entity
{
    public RelationEntity_Id int{ get; set; }
    public RelationEntity Relation { get; set; }
}

class RelationEntity : Entity
{
}
```

With the following syntax there is such a check on the types:

```
public IQueryable<SomeEntity> SearchByRelation(RelationEntity relation)
{
    return CreateQueryable().Where(e => s.Relation == relation);
}
```

With the following one, we are only comparing int and this could be error prone :

```
public IQueryable<SomeEntity> SearchByRelation(RelationEntity relation)
{
    return CreateQueryable().Where(e => s.Relation.Id == relation.Id);
}
```

Because EntityFramework needs to be told how the comparison on objects should be done, I'm looking for a way create a generic Expression returning an expression Comparing the Id of a `SomeEntity` with the Id of a `RelationEntity`.

Something like this :

```
public IQueryable<SomeEntity> SearchByRelation(RelationEntity relation)
{
    return CreateQueryable().Where(e => AreEquals(s.Relation, relation));
}
```

AreEquals would be adapting the Expression Tree for the SQL generated correctly comparing on entity Ids.

I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10423451/4306452) which seems to be a good start, but I can't get it to append the '.Id' part of the Expression.

Any idea of how I could achieve this, or what could be the good way to go ?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

The helper function (inside some static class):

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereEquals<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, T target)
    where T : Entity
{
    var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
    var body = Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(item, "Id"),
        Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(target), "Id"));
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, item);
    return source.Where(predicate);
}
```

and the usage:

```
public IQueryable<SomeEntity> SearchByRelation(RelationEntity relation)
{
    return CreateQueryable().WhereEquals(relation);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev, but I think this is not correct because you are performing:

`CreateQueryable().Where(e => e.Id == relation.Id);`

not

`CreateQueryable().Where(e => s.Relation.Id == relation.Id);`

Comment: @Koresh Correct, I didn't think it's important once we meet the compile time checking goal.  Fortunately it can easily be corrected - see the updated answer.