# Asp.net web api linq query generic type

Tags: c#, asp.net, generic-programming

```
public class Entity<T> : IEntity<T>
    where T:struct
{
  public T ID { get; set; }
  public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

public class EntityRepository<T,Y> : IRepository<T,Y>
    where T : Entity<Y>
    where Y : struct
{
  public virtual async Task<T> GetByID(Y id)
  {
    return await con.Set<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ID == id && !p.IsDeleted);
  } 
}
```

I have a generic domain and repository.
My problem is **cannot be applied 'Y' and 'Y'**

Comment: Can you please supply the full error message, and what line of code it occurs on?

Comment: p.ID == id is problem.

Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Y' and 'Y'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Equals` method:

```
p => p.ID.Equals(id)
```

Comment: @anılyıldırım please update question and show us how you create `EntityRepository`

Comment: Your solutions is not work.  
exceptionMessage=Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Comment: @anılyıldırım it looks like your problem is somewhere in unshown code. I simply replaced `==` with `Equals` and [it works](http://ideone.com/TabOuy) for me.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like you're comparing a type T (which is a defined struct) with a generic type Y (I'm assuming that at runtime this will also actually be a type T).

Your problem is likely that you havent overloaded the equality operators for your struct.

```
public static bool operator ==(MyStruct arg1, MyStruct arg2) 
{
    return arg1.Equals(arg2);
}

public static bool operator !=(MyStruct arg1, MyStruct arg2)
{
   return !arg1.Equals(arg2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It's okey**

```
public class EntityRepository<T,Y> : IRepository<T,Y>
          where T : Entity<Y>
          where Y : struct
    {
 public virtual async Task<T> GetByID(Y id, bool isDeleted=false)
        {
            var result = await con.Set<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=>(object)x.ID==(object)id);
            return result;
        } 

    }
```

Comment: No, that's not okay. It works with Entity Framework, but not on Linq to Objects. You need to constrain Y to be `IComparable`, and then your original code will compile just fine.

Answer (score -1):

As a following answer, you can use simple hack, code below ;)

```
Repository.Get<TEntity, TKey>(e => (object)e.Id == (object)EntityId);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10423451/7511392

Comment: this question already has an answer.